# In R, if site and date match in two data frames, pull row values from first data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have two data frames that both have a `site ID` and `Date` column. The first data frame (`df1`) has continuous dates and also includes a temperature measurement (`Temp.`) associated with each date. The second data frame (`df2`) has the `Date` of when the maximum temperature was reached at every `site ID`. What I would like is to have an R code that determines if the `site ID` and `Date` in `df2` match in `df1`, then the associated temperature value from `df1` gets added to `df2`.

```
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 9))
x <- c("site ID", "Date", "Temp.")
colnames(df1) <- x
df1$`site ID` <- c("a","a","a",
                "b","b","b",
                "c","c","c")
df1$Date <- rep(seq(from = as.Date("2020-01-01"), to = as.Date("2020-01-03"), by = 1),3)  
df1$Temp. <- c("10","12","11",
               "20","15","10",
               "2","4","6")

df2 <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = 3))
y <- c("site ID", "Date")
colnames(df2) <- y
df2$`site ID` <- c("a","b","c")
df2$Date <- c(as.Date("2020-01-02"), as.Date("2020-01-01"), as.Date("2020-01-03"))
```

The ideal output would look like this below:

```
  site ID       Date Temp.
1       a 2020-01-02    12
2       b 2020-01-01    20
3       c 2020-01-03     6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base `R` you can use the `merge` function to do a left-join (`all.x = T`), which will keep all dates in `df2` even if they're not found in `df1`. If the date is in `df2`, but not `df1` then you will get an `NA` for `Temp`.

You can delete this if you want to do an inner-join where only matching dates in each dataframe are found.

```
merge(df2, df1, by = c("site ID", "Date"), all.x = T)

  site ID       Date Temp.
1       a 2020-01-02    12
2       b 2020-01-01    20
3       c 2020-01-03     6
```